# select query for >= jsonb column value in postgresql

Tags: sql, json, postgresql, postgresql-9.5

I have a postgres database with `jsonb` format column `tags`in table.  I am trying to query for rows where the `confidence >= 50`.

I am unsure how to index into the predictions list to check for the confidence. I have tried the query below it executes without error but doesn't return any rows.

`select * from mytable where (tags->>'confidence')::int >= 50;`

Here is an example row jsonb

```
{
    "predictions": [
        {
            "label": "Shopping",
            "confidence": 91
        },
        {
            "label": "Entertainment",
            "confidence": 4
        },
        {
            "label": "Events",
            "confidence": 2
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to normalize the data by un-nest the array, then you can

```
select p.d
from mytable mt
  cross join lateral jsonb_array_elements(mt.tags -> 'predictions') as p(d)
where (p.d ->> 'confidence')::int >= 50;
```

For the above sample data, that returns:

```
{"label": "Shopping", "confidence": 91}
```

Online example: http://rextester.com/CBIAR76462

Comment: Thanks, but not sure how to unnest the array. should I do : `select p.d
from mytable mt
  cross join lateral jsonb_array_elements(unnest(mt.tags) -> 'predictions') as p(d)
where (p.d ->> 'confidence')::int >= 50;` . sorry am a pgsql newbie.

Comment: `jsonb_array_elements` does the unnesting

Comment: hmm am not getting any results from running the query you provided. not sure what I am doing wrong :/